# Accessing variables from an object of array in Java

Tags: java

**Interface Price:**

```
interface Price     {
    void printPrice();     }
```

**AbstractTest class:**

```
abstract class AbstractTest implements Price     {
        private String name, surname;

        AbstractTest (String name, String surname){
            this.name=name;
            this.surname=surname;     }

    public String getName()     {
        return this.name;     }

    public String getSurname()     {
        return this.surname;     }     }
```

**TestAbstractTest class:**

```
class TestAbstractTest extends AbstractTest{
    int price;

    TestAbstractTest(int price, String name, String surname){
        super(name, surname);
        this.price=price;     }

    void printPrice()     {
        System.out.println("price:"+ price)// HOW CAN I ACCESS TO NAME AND SURNAME FROM AbstractTest CLASS     }
```

**Main class:**

```
  class Main { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
       AbstractTest[] abstracttest= new AbstractTest[2];
       abstracttest[0]=new TestAbstractTest(5, xxx, yyy);
       abstracttest[1]=new TestAbstractTest(10, aaa, zzz);     }
```

I want to access the name and the surname from subclasses method printPrice.

I cant create an abstract method. I have to use printPrice from the interface Price. I've rearranged the constructor of TestAbstractTest like this (price, name, surname, AbstractTest abstracttest) and i've tried this.

```
abstracttest[0]= new AbstractTest(5, "xxx", "00yy", abstracttest[0])
```

But its obviously wrong. How can I access name and surname and print it from printPrice method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring or requesting a variable's value you can use get() or set() methods.

```
abstracttest[0]= new AbstractTest(5, this.getName(), this.getSurname(), abstracttest[0]);

 System.out.println("price:"+ this.getPrice() );
```

You need to implement getPrice() of course.